# Use yum install or Install application from source - apache2

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, installation, yum

I  have a requirement of installing apache2 into a Linux Machine eg: Centos 6.3.

This can be done by:

Installing apache2 from source : Downloading the .tar file from the site and running

```
$ ./configure  
$ make
$ make install
```

OR i could install it directly using the internet eg: `$ yum install httpd`

What is the best method i could use to install apache out of  above  mentioned methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software dependency issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/489628/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-dependency-issue)

Answer (score 3):

Well, for one, it'd be `yum install httpd`.

What's your goal?

Installing with `yum` will get you an installation from your OS package.  It'll get patched with a simple `yum update` and will be easily kept up to date.

Installing from source will get you the application's current release.  You'll get newer code, which might be good (new features!) or bad (new bugs...) - the OS packages avoid this by using a set version with backported changes when needed (critical bugs and security problems).  Any future patches will need to be compiled and installed by you manually.

Comment: If my servers don't have access to internet, i will have to install the application from source right?

Comment: @user170899: No you just create a local yum repository (lots of info via google) and use sneakernet. Going for source is the last thing you should do.

Comment: Just some clarification: "Going for source is the last thing you should do" If using a package based Distribution.

Answer (score 0):

My general rule of thumb is:

use yum if it's not a production host or otherwise a critical host

install from source for situations where a lot of people rely on the host, a lot of people use its services, or where performance is a concern.

The thinking here is that with yum you get stuff up and running quickly and which satisfies most basic needs, but for mission-critical applications or other such things, you want to be able to finely control the version, the modules that you need, etc.