# How to fix dependenies error in this case? (centos 6)

Tags: centos

I try fix dependencies problem in this case. Can I get advise?

```
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
mysql = 5.1.73-5.el6_6 is needed by (installed) mysql-server-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64
** Found 13 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
coreutils-8.4-37.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of coreutils-libs = ('0', '8.4', '37.el6')
coreutils-libs-8.4-43.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of coreutils = ('0', '8.4', '43.el6')
1:cups-libs-1.4.2-74.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:cups-libs-1.4.2-72.el6.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.1.i686 has missing requires of glibc-common = ('0', '2.12', '1.166.el6_7.1')
glibc-2.14.90-14.x86_64 is a duplicate with glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.1.i686
libXinerama-1.1.3-4.fc23.i686 is a duplicate with libXinerama-1.1.3-2.1.el6.x86_64
libXrandr-1.4.2-2.fc23.i686 is a duplicate with libXrandr-1.4.1-2.1.el6.x86_64
libicu-4.2.1-14.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with libicu-4.2.1-12.el6.x86_64
mysql-5.5.52-1.el6.remi.x86_64 has missing requires of real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = ('0', '5.5.52', '1.el6.remi')
mysql-devel-5.5.52-1.el6.remi.x86_64 has missing requires of libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
mysql-devel-5.5.52-1.el6.remi.x86_64 has missing requires of real-mysql-libs(x86-64) = ('0', '5.5.52', '1.el6.remi')
mysql-server-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 has missing requires of mysql = ('0', '5.1.73', '5.el6_6')
poppler-0.12.4-10.el6.x86_64 is a duplicate with poppler-0.12.4-4.el6_6.1.x86_64
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx-2016-10-21-11-567RNI_J.yumtx
```

1. I want remove @remi repos package (downgrade)
2. I want fix glibc package version error

How Can I do?

Comment: Related http://serverfault.com/q/489628/340408

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`sudo yum install yum-plugin-replace`

`sudo yum replace mysql-5.5.52 --replace-with=mysql-5.1.73`

also, may not work, downgrade a version is not so easy